# MySQL - how to compute incremental charges?

Tags: mysql

Assume a service is billed in the following manner:

- The first 60 seconds is charged at $1.00
- Subsequent charges are billed at $0.25 per 10 second

The following are example computations:

- 32 seconds = $1.00
- 59 seconds = $1.00
- 60 seconds = $1.00
- 61 seconds = $1.25
- 69 seconds = $1.25
- 70 seconds = $1.25
- 71 seconds = $1.50

Is it possible to do this kind of computation in MySQL alone?

**EDIT 1:**

Does something like this work:

```
SELECT `call_length`, 
       ( 1.00 + ( Round(( `call_length` - 30 ) / 10) * .25 ) ) AS `cost` 
FROM   `service`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5135c2/12/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE sec(val INT);

INSERT INTO sec
VALUES (32), (59), (60), (61), (69), (70), (71);

SELECT 
  val,
  1.0 + CASE 
          WHEN val <= 60.0 THEN 0
          WHEN val MOD 10 = 0 THEN  0.25 *((val - 60) DIV 10)
          ELSE 0.25 * (((val - 60) DIV 10) + 1)
        END AS charge
FROM sec;
```

## EDIT:

Without `CASE`:

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a0c0/12/0)**

```
SELECT 
  call_length,
  1.0 + IF( call_length <= 60, 0, 0.25 * CEIL((call_length - 60)/10)) AS cost
FROM service;
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at my solution as well as @Thernys? Does this really need a CASE statement?

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie Your solution will produce http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a0c0/2/0 incorrect values.

Comment: I see that now. Is the CASE statement necessary? Is there a solution that doesn't use CASE?

Comment: I was mistaken. The results are correct. Thanks, I think I can build on top of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not much of a MySQL problem, unless the setting in which you need to perform the calculation is somehow difficult(?).

```
UPDATE ... SET cost_cents =  100 + CEIL(GREATEST(0, duration - 60)/10) * 25;
```

As a `SELECT` to match your edit,

```
SELECT `call_length`, 
    100 + CEIL(GREATEST(0, `call_length` - 60)/10) * 25 AS `cost`
FROM `service`
```

Note that this returns cents. For dollars, divide the result by 100...

```
SELECT `call_length`, 
    (100 + CEIL(GREATEST(0, `call_length` - 60)/10) * 25) / 100 AS `cost`
FROM `service`
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at my attempt and let me know how our solutions differ? I think I understand your use of `ceil`. Not sure about `greatest`?

Comment: GREATEST() just ensures that `duration-60` never dips into the negatives. So, you divide the seconds in excess of 60 by 10, and CEIL() ensures that partial 10-second periods are 'rounded up'.

Comment: Can you rewrite your solution as a SELECT? I'd like to try it against http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5135c2/12/0

Comment: It does work, it just returns cents instead of dollars. If you would like the dollar value, just divide the whole thing by 100.